# Django Query to Combine Multiple ArrayFields to one text string

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have an object model where `Documents` are long text files that can have `Attachments` and both sets of objects can also have spreadsheet-like `Tables`. Each table has a rectangular array with text. I want users to be able to search for a keyword across the table contents, but the results will be displayed by the main document (so instead of seeing each table that matches, you'll just see the document that has the most tables that match your query).

Below you can see a test query I'm trying to run that in an ideal world would convert all of the table contents (across all attachments) to one long string, that I can then pass to a SearchHighlight to make the headline. For some reason, the test query returns the tables as different objects, rather than concatenated to one long string.
I'm using a custom function that mimics the Postgres 13 `StringAgg` as I'm using Postgres 10.

Thanks in advance for your help, let me know if I need to provide more information to replicate this.

my `models.py`:

```
class Document(AbstractDocument):
  tables = GenericRelation(Table)

class Attachment(AbstractDocument):
  tables_new = GenericRelation(Table)  
  main_document = ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="attachments")

class Table(models.Model):
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  object_id = models.SlugField()
  content_object = GenericForeignKey()

  content = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.TextField(null=True)))
```

my query:

```
def myStringAgg(field: str):
  return Func(
    F(field),
    Value(" "),
    Value(""),
    function="array_to_string",
    output_field=models.TextField(),
  )


s = Document.objects.all() \
  .annotate(tt=myStringAgg("attachments__tables__content")) \
  .values_list('tt', flat=True)
# what I get
>>> <DocumentSet ['table1', 'table2']>
# what I want
>>> <DocumentSet ['table1 table2']>
```

I'm using `Django 3.2` and `Postgres 10`.

To clarify what my full scope is, this what the final query would look like:

```
qs = Document.objects.filter(  
  Q(tables__search_vector=query) | 
  Q(attachments__tables__search_vector=query)
  )
  .annotate(rank=rank)
  .order_by("-rank")
  .annotate(snippet=SearchHeadline(
     myStringAgg("attachments__tables__content"),
   query, max_fragments=5)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the join function to create a string from a list:
s = Document.objects.all() \
  .annotate(tt=myStringAgg("attachments__tables__content")) \
  .values_list('tt', flat=True)

s = " ". join(list(s))
```

Comment: This won't work as I'm passing the resulting string to further SQL processing (going into SearchHeadline function call). So I need the join to happen in the SQL query, not after.